# Find any element in a map by matching a sub-element of the key

Tags: c++, clr, stdmap

I have a `std::map` whose key is another class. Like the example below:

```
class KeyClass
{
public:
  int a;
  int b;
};

main(){
    //some code
    std::map<KeyClass, SomeOtherClass> mapVariable;
    KeyClass k1(); k1.a = 1; k1.b = 1;
    KeyClass k2(); k2.a = 2; k2.b = 2;
    mapVariable[k1] = SomeOtherClass();
    mapVariable[k2] = SomeOtherClass();

    //I am trying something like see if any element is there whose key.a = 1 (or may be key.a = 6 --> will fail here)?
}
```

I tried looping across `mapVariable` and checking `iter->first.a == 1`, but is there anyway I can use the `map::count()` function to get that?

I am using this in a CLI C++ code, so it seem that I am unable to use a lambda function.

Comment: FYI, your `KeyClass` needs an `operator<` defined in order to be usable as a `std::map` key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) with a lambda:

```
auto it = std::find_if(mapVariable.begin(), mapVariable.end(), [](const auto& pair) {
    return pair.first.a == 1; // first is the key, second is the value
});
```

Or without using a lambda:

```
struct Functor {
    bool operator()(const decltype(mapVariable)::value_type& pair) const {
        return pair.first.a == 1;
    }
};

auto it = std::find_if(mapVariable.begin(), mapVariable.end(), Functor{});
```

Then check if you got a match:

```
if(it != mapVariable.end()) {
    // match found
}
```

To be able to use the [`size_type std::map::count( const K& x ) const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/count) overload, the comparison function used in the map would need to be transparent.

Example:

```
struct Compare {
    using is_transparent = int;

    bool operator()(int x, const KeyClass& b) const {
        return x < b.a;
    }
    bool operator()(const KeyClass& a, int x) const {
        return a.a < x;
    }
    bool operator()(const KeyClass& a, const KeyClass& b) const {
        return a.a < b.a;
    }
};

//...
    std::map<KeyClass, SomeOtherClass, Compare> mapVariable;
    //...
    if(mapVariable.count(1)) {
        // match found
    }
```

Comment: Is there any other we can use apart than lambda function? As I am using it in CLI/C++ code, its not allowing me to use lambda function

Comment: @Humble_Aspirant I have very little knowledge about C++/CLI. It's a different language than C++ I'm afraid. You should change the language tag of the question from [tag:c++] to [tag:c++-cli] if that's what you are using.

Comment: @Humble_Aspirant a lambda is just syntax sugar for a functor - a `class`/`struct` with an `operator()` defined. You can define a functor manually

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::find_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to search the map using a custom predicate, eg:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

using myMapType = std::map<KeyClass, SomeOtherClass>;
myMapType mapVariable;
...
auto iter = std::find_if(
    mapVariable.begin(), mapVariable.end(),
    [](const myMapType::value_type &entry){ return entry.first.a == 1; }
);
if (iter != mapVariable.end()) {
    ...
}
```

If using a lambda is not an option, you can use a functor instead:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::map<KeyClass, SomeOtherClass> myMapType;

struct findKey
{
    bool operator()(const myMapType::value_type &entry) const { return entry.first.a == 1; }
};

myMapType mapVariable;
...
myMapType::iterator iter = std::find_if(mapVariable.begin(), mapVariable.end(), findKey());
if (iter != mapVariable.end()) {
    ...
}
```

If you don't want to use `std::find_if()`, you can use a manual loop:

```cpp
myMapType::iterator iter = mapVariable.begin();
while (iter != mapVariable.end()) {
    if (iter->first.a == 1) break;
    ++iter;
}
if (iter != mapVariable.end()) {
    ...
}
```